# 1996 40hp mariner magnum - no start

Tags: small-engine, outboard

The above mentioned motor is new to me.  Since it was new to me and I couldn’t be sure if the oil injector was working, I mixed 10 liters fuel 50:1 so I could see if it was consuming oil.

After running a while I ran out of gas (shocked at fast it ran out). At this point I checked the oil reservoir and confirmed it was consuming oil. This being the case, I put straight gas in this time. After cranking a short time it started up fine.

By the time I untied the lines to cast off, the engine stopped. No shutter, no sputter, no banging. Almost as if the key is as turned off.

I tried restarting a few time but nothing. Thought maybe it was flooded so waited an hour. Still nothing. Removed the spark plugs and they were wet. Cleaned them up, waited 15 min and tried again, still nothing. Took plugs out, looked dry, hmmm, poured a little mixed gas in the cylinders and tried again. Still nothing.

Any thoughts?

So an update. I got a spark tester. No spark.
It doesn’t have a kill switch, so not that. Any suggestions on how I should start narrowing down the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recheck to ensure you have spark. If the plugs were dry, then you added fuel directly to the cylinders, it should have fired, if even for a short while. Considering how you said it shut off, the ignition seems the most likely culprit. If it was fuel starved, it would have sputtered/coughed at least a little before dying. Same as if it were flooded.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I’m out at a water access only cottage right now. My brother is coming by tomorrow with a spark tester. Hopefully will get more of an idea then. I have a feeling I’m going to get towed back to the mainland. Sucks!!